# Classlist toggle doesn't add/toggle class name for a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My goal is to display a list everytime the button is pressed kind of like a dropdown list, so I made a sort of test html,css and js files and somehow it doesn't work, the log function in my js code outputs the word 'year' on the console but the class list toggle doesn't seem to change/add the "active" on the divs' class.

Below is my js.

```
function btnFunction(identifier){
console.log(identifier)
var element = document.getElementById(identifier);
element.classList.toggle("active");}
```

Below is my html.

```
<div class="modal-content-col-6-drop">
  <button onclick="btnFunction('year')" class="drop-btn">sample</button>
</div>

 <div id="year" class="select">
    <ul>
      <li>0 Year</li>
      <li>1 Year</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Below is my css.

```
#year{
  display: none;
}
.active{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css selctor based on id is prioritized over one based on class. So the id year will always be `display: none` even if it has the class active. The best solution is to not use ids for css selectors because of this.

A better solution would be

```
.select{
  display: none;
}
.select.active{
  display: block;
}
```

You can read more about selector specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Ill include a snippet that shows this under here:

```js
function btnFunction(identifier){
    console.log(identifier)
    var element = document.getElementById(identifier);
    element.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.select{
  display: none;
}
.select.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="modal-content-col-6-drop">
  <button onclick="btnFunction('year')" class="drop-btn">sample</button>
</div>

 <div id="year" class="select">
    <ul>
      <li>0 Year</li>
      <li>1 Year</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: like I said the classlist toggle doesn't seem to change/add the word "active" on the divs class name.

Comment: Ill see if i can fix that also.

Comment: how the....... on my side it's still not working.........

Comment: okay now it works, I switched laptop and somehow it works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `!important` in your css

```js
function btnFunction(identifier) {
  console.log(identifier)
  var element = document.getElementById(identifier);
  element.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
#year{
  display: none;
}
.active{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content-col-6-drop">
  <button onclick="btnFunction('year')" class="drop-btn">sample</button>
</div>

 <div id="year" class="select">
    <ul>
      <li>0 Year</li>
      <li>1 Year</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please dont use !important. Trust me, it will create unmaintainable code..

Comment: @IAmGroot0517 and yet it works well in this snippet, you probably have another problem in your code

Comment: @Mister Jojo Just because something exist doesnt mean its a good idea to use it for all tasks. The Bazooka was not created by misstake either but i dont think its resonable to use for hunting squirrels.

Comment: @Achtung A metaphor is not proof. This use of css answers his question and it is in no way excessive to present it here

Comment: @Mister Jojo This isnt a scientific discussion, im not looking to prove but to explain. And I insist that it is excessive, important is destructive to maintainable code and is generally conciderd to be so. For example by MDN: 
`Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets.`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity